# to Perform Recurring billing Tasks

Tags: paypal

1. We want to setup recurring payments option on our website.
   Customer "X" visits our website & registers and the registration amount depends on some parameters - so its not 1 fixed amount.
   So for this kind of registration - which type of PayPal button would need to be created?
2. Once the Customer "X" successfully registers by paying, for example: USD $34 on 15th July 2015 - then when (date) will the Customer "X" be charged again?
   3.There are some more features on our website - which our customers can subscribe for i.e. Additional bins.
   Say for example: registered customer "X" subscribes for more additional bins - costing USD $12 and makes the payment and this amount also needs to be recurring again.
   For this feature - which type of PayPal button needs to be created?
   4.Once the Customer "X" successfully subscribe for Additional bins by paying USD $12 on 25th July 2015 - then when (date) will the Customer "X" be charged again?
   5.Can we combine Customer "X" amounts USD $34 + $12 and charge once every 15th of the month?
   Is this possible? If YES then what are the steps to implement this feature?

Answer (score 1):

For your first question have look [Subscriptions and Recurring Payments Setup](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/get-started/recurring-payment-processing) or go for [Classic API Reference](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/).

For your second question, if your customer registers (recurring profile creation) on 15th July, USD $34 than it charges next depending on your `BILLINGPERIOD` and `BILLINGFREQUENCY` lets say you set

```
BILLINGPERIOD=Day 
BILLINGFREQUENCY=1
```

than it charges your customer on next day i.e. 16th July with the same amount provided that you haven't set any INITIALPAYMENT.

Now if your customer make some edit in his plan on 25th July, than what I did in my case, delete his previous profile and created new which recur on 25th Aug (for monthly billing period). I handled this situation by license file creation at my server,like the services purchased on 15th July will expire on 15th Aug but will not recur as profile was cancelled and the new license which he purchased on 25th keep continue to recur.